# CSS Selectors, Choose by CHILD values

Tags: python, css, selenium, css-selectors

Let say I have an html structure like this:

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
            <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>Left</td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>Center</td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>Right</td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to construct CSS selectors to access the three sub tables, which are only distinguished by the contents of a table data item in their first row.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you intend to select each table separately with a different selector?

Comment: Yes, I need three selectors. And they cannot be based on location.

Comment: This would break the concept of separation of content and layout. Bad idea. Better to use JavaScript.

Comment: I am not creating the page.  I have to work with what is there.  If I could change the page I would put IDs on all the elements and save myself worlds of work.

Comment: @Diodeus: He's querying the elements using Selenium, so that's quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think there no such method available in css selector to verify the inner text.

You can achieve that by using xpath or jQuery path.

**xpath :**

> ```
>    "//td[contains(text(),'Left')]"
>
>                or
>
>      "//td[text()='Right']"
> ```

jQuery path

> ```
>     jQuery("td:contains('Centre')")
> ```

Using below logic you can execute jQuery paths in WebDriver automation.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element=(WebElement)js.executeScript(locator);
```

Comment: Well, that gives me the cell with that contents, but I can get that a number of ways.  I need to get the TABLE that contains that cell in the first position of the first row.

Answer (score 1):

the .text method on an element returns the text of an element.

```
tables = page.find_elements_by_xpath('.//table')
contents = "Left Center Right".split()
results = []
for table in tables: 
    if table.find_element_by_xpath('.//td').text in contents: # returns only the first element
         results.append(table)
```

You can narrow the search field by setting 'page' to the first 'table' element, and then running your search over that.  There are all kinds of ways to improve performance like this.  Note, this method will be fairly slow if there are a lot of extraneous tables present.  Each webpage will have it's quirks on how it chooses to represent information, make sure you work around those to gain efficiency.

You can also use list comprehension to return your results.

```
results = [t for t in tables if t.find_element_by_xpath('.//td').text in contents]
```